# jQuery Dropdown menu not displaying menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap dropdown menu with this code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <!-- Link or button to toggle dropdown -->
        <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Looking at the Bootstrap docs, this is about the bare minimum needed for a dropdown menu, there is no other explanation provided in the docs. I have referenced Bootstrap and jQuery. I do not understand how this is supposed to work - <del>and it doesn't in this current sample</del>. 
Well obviously it needs something to tell it to show the menu, but I haven't been able to find a straight answer on what reference and file does what for the Bootstrap dropdown menu.

**Question:** So does this thing use jQuery to work or what? I don't understand why or how it works even after I found a simple working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/2bXmT/1/) from this SO question stackoverflow.com/questions/14023115/dropdown-menu-not-showing-in-bootstrap. 
I got it to work in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7pD2/) after importing Bootstrap.css and Bootstrap.min.js and Jquery 2. So it needs both Bootstrap.min.js AND Jquery to work? Huh? I'm just completely lost here. Thanks.

EDIT: Okay, found out that bootstrap.js needs to be loaded after jquery to work. But I still do not understand how the menu works. Does Bootstrap.js need Jquery?

Comment: You need to call it in javascript: 
`$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`

Comment: @niklas, Do I need to call it if I am just trying to click it to get it to drop down?

Comment: check their docs - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns 
you should call your dropdown, sry, I corrected the selector above, it should be attached to button

Comment: @niklaz, The doc says by Data Attribute (clicking due to the `<a>`?) or by JS. If dropdown is to be triggered by the user's mouse click, should `.dropdown()` be called by an attached click handler to the dropdown button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All js plugins in bootstrap uses jquery

> **Plugin dependencies**
>
> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you
>   include plugins individually, make sure to check for these
>   dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery
>   (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files).

source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: Okay, I missed that on the site, thanks. 

When I look at event handlers for the dropdown link <a>, they all reference the jquery.js file. I don't understand how bootstrap.js ever comes into play if it is never triggered.

Comment: bootstrap triggers the jquery plugins in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The following post should help you.

[Why doesn't this bootstrap dropdown example work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766486/why-doesnt-this-bootstrap-dropdown-example-work)

You are gonna need both jquery and bootstrap referenced in the correct order and with html 5 doctype.