# Why is the bootstrap navbar not working?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

im starting study bootstrap and im doing a basic example with a nav bar.
I went to bootstrap documentation for navbar here -> "http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar" and i copy the code to my project, but the menu appears all unformatted. What could be wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="topo">
                <div class="span5">
                    <a href="index.html" title="Index">
                        <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div><!--end top-->

            <div class="row" id="navegation">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                            <ul class="nav">
                              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
          </div><!--end navegation-->
    </div><!--end container-->


    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

what im getting is:
[image]

Comment: Hopefully this is a stupid question, but did you download Bootstrap and place it in the css folder in your project?

Comment: Yes...sure! Im starting studying boostrap but  i already know the basics at least of html & css :)

Comment: You are reading the documentation for Bootstrap version 2.  Are you sure the files you downloaded are for the same version and not version 3?  The navbar is structured differently in version 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right, i download the last version of boostrap but the example i get from the bootstrap site was for the version 2. Thanks for help one more time :)

Comment: No problem.  I gave that as the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have downloaded Bootstrap 3 files but are reading Bootstrap 2 documentation.

Your code with Bootstrap 2 files works fine:  http://jsbin.com/vazesuto/1/edit

But with Bootstrap 3 files it produces the error you have shown: http://jsbin.com/vazesuto/3/edit

Try reading the navbar documentation for Bootstrap 3 instead: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 1):

How did you copy the links to bootstrap? Cause in that sample code it's assuming you have it somewhere in your computer, instead of linking directly to it, like the JQuery script source is doing. If you haven't, you need to download bootstrap first, and then write the appropiate path (depending on where you're placing it on your computer).

**Edit**: After upgrading to the latest version of bootstrap, please make sure you're following what's written on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10766531/1499934), as the OP seemed to be having the same problem as you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ana. I already download the bootstrap files and   Im call the files with "href" in the right location!